# Class 'Mandrill\Struct' not found while using mandrill api to send mail

Tags: php, mandrill

I am using mandrill's api for sending email through my project made in core php. i followed steps as given [here](https://github.com/jlinn/mandrill-api-php)

Instead of adding as 'use' i have included  the respective files in my page & called the api. But it has shown me the above error. The architecture of api is little bit framework like. I havent worked on framework yet. Don't have any idea how it can be resolved.

i did following

```
include '../api/mandrill-api-php/vendor/autoload.php';
include '../api/mandrill-api-php/vendor/jlinn/mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill/Mandrill.php';
include '../api/mandrill-api-php/vendor/jlinn/mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill/Struct/Message.php';
include '../api/mandrill-api-php/vendor/jlinn/mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill/Struct/Recipient.php';
```

it is showing me error class mandrill not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including only those 3 dependencies is not enough, because mandrill has other dependencies on its classes. What you could do is install the mandrill-api using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) as suggested in mandrill-api readme:

```
php composer.phar require jlinn/mandrill-api-php:~1.0
```

Then, in your php, include the autoload file:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: now it has shown me that class mandrill not found. check the edit part

Comment: Don't include the mandrill files. Only the autoload.php. And you must have the `use ...` statements as in the readme example.